# IE 11 related issue - Background Image not displaying

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

I am using arrow images on the page from as background-image but he image is not visible in the page:

[image]

But it is visible when using any other browser than IE, please see below screen shot. But if i use any other image also, that also doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set background image in html that work in Internet explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449185/how-to-set-background-image-in-html-that-work-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you disable the show pictures option in IE browser, please refer to the following steps to enable display pictures:

Open IE browser, go to **Internet Options**, under the **Advanced** tab, scroll down to **Multimedia Section** and check **Show Pictures** check-box, click **Apply** and Exit.

[image]

If still not working, try to click the Reset... button inside the above picture to reset the IE browser setting.

Comment: Awesome. That works. I didn't know when I disabled it.